# Zend_Form and Float number localization

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, zend-form

I'm using Zend_Form for handling a form and I have a problem with localization.

I use following field declaration:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'area', array(
        'label' => 'Area:',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'NormalizedToLocalized')
    ));
```

The problem is, I use pl_PL locale and in this locale the decimal point separator is "," not ".".  But database (MySQL) stores float with "." separator.

I added NormalizedToLocalized to convert e.g. 40.12 into 40,12 in my html form.

But when passing 40,12 in POST request I want Zend_Form to automatically convert back value 40,12 into 40.12 so that it can be passed to DB (I collect values from form using $form->getValues() method). By now it renders 40,12 successfully but in $form->getValues() I get localized, not not normalized value.

So my question is, whether it is possible to create different filter for rendering and getting value of field in Zend Framework.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filters are not applied until the form is submitted so `'NormalizedToLocalized'` will not have any effect until the form is posted. So if you want decimal points and not commas in your data for storage remove the filter (or use `'LocalizedToNormalized'`) from the form and apply the filter using [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) for any data you need to display.
If this field always expects a float type you can use a [validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.float) to enforce the value and then use the filter to enforce formating for the database.

```
$this->addElement('text', 'area', array(
        'label' => 'Area:',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array('Float'),
        'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'LocalizedToNormalized')
    ));
```

Comment: This works from form to database but if data are displayed (e.g. in case of edit or when the form re-displays because another field does not validate) it displays normalized.

Comment: You have to be aware of which data set you working with. The filters are only going to be applied to the form element values normally access via `$form->getValues()` or similar, the filters won't normally be applied to the $_POST array, which is the data set usually passed back to the form after failed validation. If you need a filter applied to data other then form data you will need to pass that data through `Zend_Filter_Input`.

Comment: I use `$this->_request->getPost()` to repopulate and `'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'LocalizedToNormalized')` and after failed validation see my localized input (,) back as normalized (.). Doesn't getPost() get the $_POST array?

Comment: Yes `getPost()` does access the $_POST array. The values from `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` should be unfiltered. (_That's what the docs say_). So when you pass the $_POST values back into the form after a failed validation, you should see whatever the original value was in the array. It is possible that when the array is passed into the form and the element's value is set, the filter may be fired, I just can't find it in the code or the docs. You may want to  dump your arrays and see what's really in them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Zend Framework but looking on filter name, shouldn't it be `'LocalizedToNormalized'` ?